# How do I write a blender addon script outside blender without having to pip install all the modules such as bpy, bmesh etc. separately?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, bmesh

I'm trying to create an add-on outside of Blender and I'm not sure how to go about installing dependencies to create it on another IDE. I don't want to use blender's script editor as it would be inconvenient as it does not have intuitive features such as autocomplete.

**Is there a global scripting library for blender or do I have to install all the required dependencies one by one?**

And if there is one, how do I access/get it?

Comment: This offers a step by step to setup python dev in visual studio code https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-microsoft-visual-studio-code-as-external-ide-for-writing-blender-scripts-add-ons/

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks, man.